# GNUPLOT: draw a circle and letters in histogram

Tags: drawing, gnuplot, draw, histogram

i want to draw a circle in an histogram with a radius equal to one and origin in x=0 and y=0. Also i want to draw a point and a letter in a particular position: x=0.5 and y=0.86 and a letter 'L_4' near the same position. Is it possible?

Here my code:

```
clear
reset

# wxt
#set terminal wxt size 350,262 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' persist
# png
set terminal pngcairo size 500,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output 'Err_rev3bp.png'

set title "\n"
set label 1 "Reversibility Error\n 3bp mu=0.001" at graph 0.5,1.15 center
set view map 
set xlabel 'x_0'
set xrange [*:*]
set ylabel 'y_0'
set yrange [*:*]
#set logscale z
set zlabel 'Err'
set border linewidth 1.0
set key outside

set pm3d at b
set dgrid 100,100 
splot 'trecorpi.txt' w pm3d notitle

exit
```

I use the following command:

```
set object 10 circle at 0,0 size 1,1 fc rgb "red"
```

But i can't see the circle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't see a circle because you are using `splot`, which renders 3D plots. Circle is a 2D object and only compatible with `plot` command instead. There is a polygon object that is compatible with `splot`, but it seems there is no sphere object available.

```
set object 1 polygon from 0,0,0 to 1,1,10 to 2,0,0
set object 1 fc rgb "cyan" fillstyle solid 1.0 border lt -1
splot x
```

[image]

Comment: I try to draw a triangle but i can't see it in my output.

Comment: I've added triangle example output.

Comment: Yes i try this and work but when i use it in my code i can see only the triangle out of the range of my density plot. So i can't overplot the triangle with my density plot.